# How to copy a folder from remote using remote user with sudo?

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

How to copy a folder from remote using remote user with sudo? None of these works on folders with permissions and fails with permission denied:

```
scp -r userwithsudo@XX.XX.XX.XX:/source/ /destination/
sudo scp -r userwithsudo@XX.XX.XX.XX:/source/ /destination/
```

When I ssh on remote and perform `sudo su` then I can view those files and folders. For me it doesn't matter to use `scp` or smth else as long as it's ssh based.

Maybe it's a limitation of `scp` to use sudo rights as security benefit. However it's really frustrating to be able to ssh, perform `sudo su` and view all the folders, however not be able to download from remote (though you can probably workaround that with `tar` and download anyway)

Comment: `ssh` to the remote host, then there, doing a `sudo scp` back to where you are isn't an option?

Comment: Maybe related to https://superuser.com/questions/138893/scp-to-remote-server-with-sudo?

Comment: same concept, but that question on superuser has an accepted answer that Centurion is trying to avoid.  Though the 3rd answer (rsync with --rsync-path) is pretty good.

Comment: Running `sudo` on your local machine does not give you root access on a remote machine.  your 2nd command `sudo scp ...` runs the local `scp` command as root, but the args tell it to connect as `userwithsudo` on the remote machine.  That user may have `sudo` privs to some or all commands but only when they actually run `sudo`....and `scp` has no way of doing that.   The only way i can think of to do what you want is with `rsync`'s  `--rsync-path=PROGRAM` option to run `sudo rsync` (perhaps with a wrapper script) as the remote `rsync` program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure which user has to use `sudo` - *local* or *remote* (or both) users? i.e. `sudo scp` affects only *local* user rights to performing `scp` command.

As a solution - try to move `source` files under another directory with *remote* user ownership and rights and check write permissions for the *local* user in place where `destination` folder should be created.

Also try to move `source` to the *remote* user home directory - i.e. what path is in `~` (it could be a result of the server security policy).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have or can give yourself NOPASSWD access (either to all commands, or just 'tar' or 'cat') it can be as simple as

```
# For a single file
ssh userwithsudo@XX.XX.XX.XX 'sudo cat /source/SINGLE_FILE' > /destination/SINGLE_FILE

# for recursive copying, use tar or cpio
ssh userwithsudo@XX.XX.XX.XX 'sudo tar -C /source/ -czf - .' | tar -C /destination/ -xzf -
```

You have to run sudo on the remote side, and then pipe the files through a program that writes stdout to a program that reads stdin.

If you need to be able to enter your password for sudo things get a lot uglier, but it can be done with rsync servers and port forwards.

Comment: This won't work unless the user is allowed to sudo with NOPASSWD.

Comment: If they have un-restricted sudo access they can give themself this ability.  But true, i should mention it in the answer

Comment: How can you this backwards? I mean the origin file is in my system and the remote part is destination

Comment: @X3MBoy ```cat /path/to/local/SINGLE_FILE | ssh userwithsudo@XX.XX.XX.XX 'sudo tee /destination/SINGLE_FILE >/dev/null' ``` for a file or ```tar -C /local/source/ -czf - . | ssh userwithsudo@XX.XX.XX.XX 'sudo tar -C /destination/ -xzf -' ``` for a directory.  (using tee for a single file because a shell redirection would happen outside the sudo, unless you use a more complicated ```/bin/sh -c``` combination)

Comment: @MConrad Thanks! This works

Comment: Using `sudo -S` it reads the password from the standard input, so you can enter your password when needed. There are drawbacks in this i.e. your user password appear on the terminal and passing by people can read it, but it's acceptable to me, since you can delete terminal history and change the password before and/or after the command.

Answer (score 0):

The file you try to get should have modified permission on it (own by root or non readable permission on this specific files & folders)
So the simplest way to get that file is to scp to the root not the user.

```
scp -r root@00.00.00.00:/source /destination/
```

[Enable root login over SSH (From RedHat)](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/V2V_Guide/Preperation_Before_the_P2V_Migration-Enable_Root_Login_over_SSH.html)

Security point of view, that is better to no allow that sort of things, but if you need to do that, you should use a key and had it to the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys